# Makeshift solution for cast alloy based on copper

Tags: casting, alloys

I'm trying to mix an alloy for casting.

The base metal must be copper and the desired physical properties are

- melting point as low as possible but below 1000°C (my makeshift crucible won't stand more than 1000°C)
- silvery appearance, yellow shade is acceptable
- no excess slag development
- mechanical properties aren't important

Here's what I investigated so far. My desired material initially was nickel silver (Cu-Ni-Zn) with an approx melting point of 900°C. I had some material which I considered to be nickel silver but I found out it was high grade copper with a thin plating of nickel silver. I have limited access to other materials.
I think I have to mix significant amounts of some white metals into it to get brighter colors and lower melting points.

What I have at hand is:

- several sorts of brass (fittings and pipes)
- CuNiFe (Pipes)
- Sn60Pb40 (Solder)
- Pb60Sn40 (Solder)
- Ag (brazing solder)

Maybe I can find materials containing higher percentages of nickel or zinc.
Special condition: I can't buy any material.

I want to avoid using the Pb contaning solder for health reasons if possible. Maybe there's a CuAg alloy with silverish appearance? How much silver do I have to add? What other alloys are possible?

Comment: Google search: https://www.thoughtco.com/common-copper-alloys-and-their-uses-603710

Comment: If the silver outside is for appearance only, consider plating it after it is cast?

Comment: @SolarMike Nice list. However it neither contains material properties nor percentages of metals. I googled a lot in advance.

Comment: @Abel Plating might be a way to go. I'll look up how different plating methods work and whether I can do it with my equipment or not. Nevertheless I have to bring down the melting point of the copper (1084°C) a little in advance to ensure my crucible and my mold will stand the temperature.

Comment: Then start with the first one on the list and do more research.

Comment: Depending on shape you need, you may be able to hot work it instead of going for melt and cast. Could just overcome 1000C in select locations with an oxy-acetalyne torch.

Answer (score 1):

German silver , as you have found is likely the only practical alloy ( Alloy C 974, 60 Cu, 16 ni, 3 Sn, 16 Zn, 5 Pb). Listed melting temp of 1070 C. You need a higher temperature furnace or , as suggested , try Ni plate.